# Realtime C Programming Example

Tags: c++, c, real-time

I want to use C or C++ to do hard realtime processing of market ticker data.  Are there any special considerations to take into account when using either language?  Such as headers or what not to do?

Regards

Comment: Perhaps others will have a more concrete answer, but your description is somewhat vague. Perhaps it would help if you could give more details about the systems you work with, how data is made available to you and what exactly you intend to do with it.

Comment: you will really want to use c++. There is no solid reason I know of to prefer C over C++. Especially if you want to developt some larger software project (which you are going have) you will definitly want to code that in an object oriented language.

Comment: "hard realtime" does not mean *really fast* you realise that right? There is a very large misconception that realtime systems imply really high performance, on the contrary, they (depending on contract) guarantee deadlines rather than any performance, I would get this difference clear in your mind before proceeding, if in doubt, at least refer to the wikipedia entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use dynamic memory allocation (malloc/free) because you can't predict the amount of time this will take. Don't use critical sections (same reason), use lock-free algorithms instead if necessary.

Comment: Agree with memory allocation issue.. But lock-free algorithms : considering realtime application would lead to other major problems...

Comment: @vrajs5: no, lock-free algorithms are necessary if you need to transfer data in or out of the real-time thread without the possibility of it needing to wait for a lock that's held by a low priority thread. Such interactions should be avoided where possible, but sometimes you need them.